# Rename columns of Pandas DataFrame using values located at fixed locations of each column

Tags: python, pandas, rename, data-cleaning

I am new to Python and am trying to import an Excel spreadsheet with multiple sheets and ~20 cols, 40 rows per sheet.

```
            Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3  
 0          NaN        NaN        NaN  
 1          NaN        NaN        NaN  
 2          NaN        NaN        NaN  
 3          NaN        NaN        NaN  
 4          NaN        NaN        NaN  
 5   Population        Sex        NaN  
 6          NaN       Male     Female  
 7      Percent        NaN        NaN  
 8          NaN        NaN        NaN  
 9          NaN       48.5       51.5  
 10         NaN        NaN        NaN  
 11        12.2       18.4        6.5  
 12        36.1       41.5       31.1  
 13        51.6       40.1       62.5
```

I am trying to rename the columns with values that currently sit within each column. Throughout the dataframe the  current column name and *location* of the new column names would always be as follows:

```
'Unnamed: 1' -> value in 5th row
'Unnamed: 2' -> value in 6th row
'Unnamed: 3' -> value in 6th row
```

However, while the positions are always the same the *values* are different, so I cannot just rename the columns

```
df = df['Sheet'].rename(columns={'Unnamed: 1':'Total population', 
                                 'Unnamed: 2':'Male', 
                                 'Unnamed: 3':'Female',
                                 })
```

I was hoping to use rename columns and iloc to say

```
'where col.name == 'Unnamed: 1', rename(column=df.iloc[5])'
'where col.name == 'Unnamed: 2', rename(column=df.iloc[6])'
'where col.name == 'Unnamed: 3', rename(column=df.iloc[6])'
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the value at the given location instead of the string. Since you have multiple sheets, you need to iterate over the dictionary to apply the renaming to all sheets:

```
for sheet in df.keys():
    df[sheet] = df[sheet].rename(columns={'Unnamed: 1': df['Unnamed: 1'].iloc[5], 
                                          'Unnamed: 2': df['Unnamed: 2'].iloc[6], 
                                          'Unnamed: 3': df['Unnamed: 3'].iloc[6],
                                 })
```

Comment: How can i iterate over all columns in the dataframe instead of just 'Sheet'?

Comment: Is your df 3-dimensional? (What is df.shape?)

Comment: Or, more generally, what is df (before you rename anything), and what is df['Sheet']?

Comment: df returns the entire spreadsheet data, and df['Sheet'] returns the first sheet of the Excel spreadsheet, which is name 'Sheet'. The df is not 3d, which is probably the issue. If I rename the columns in the sheet using df['Sheet'].rename and the specific values, then df.shape returns (3, 79).

Comment: Sounds a bit like you have a dictionary of dataframes named df? If that is the case, you can iterate over df.keys(). Also then assign the result of the renaming only to that entry, not to df. So df[sheet] = df[sheet].rename(...)

Comment: What function did you use to import the data?

Comment: Ah, it says in the documentation that it will return a dictionary of dataframes if you specify multiple sheets! So then the solution would be to iterate over df.keys(). I'll include that in the answer.

Comment: If this helped you, I would appreciate if you could accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
n = [5,6,6]
df.columns = df.values[n].diagonal()
```

**Output**

```
df
    Population  Male  Female
0          NaN   NaN     NaN
1          NaN   NaN     NaN
2          NaN   NaN     NaN
3          NaN   NaN     NaN
4          NaN   NaN     NaN
5   Population   Sex     NaN
6          NaN  Male  Female
7      Percent   NaN     NaN
8          NaN   NaN     NaN
9          NaN  48.5    51.5
10         NaN   NaN     NaN
11        12.2  18.4     6.5
12        36.1  41.5    31.1
13        51.6  40.1    62.5
```

Comment: This only works if the columns always appear in the same order

Comment: @Keine_Eule in that case one have to choose a different `n`

Comment: The columns do always appear in the same order, so that works. However, it returns ''builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable' unless I specificy df['Sheet']  so I can't apply it to the entire df.